# Using a variable in the FROM clause

Tags: mysql

I need to choose a table  according to an instruction. But if I use a variable to store the name of the table, MySQL returns `error 1064`.

```
SET @eligetabla ='convenios';
select * from @eligetabla;
```

How can I use a variable for a `table` following the `from` clause?

Answer (score 1):

Not that I think this is a particularly fantastic idea, and its quite the pain, but you can do this:

```
SET @eligetabla='convenios';
SET @sql=CONCAT("SELECT * FROM ", @eligetabla);
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

You may as well be choosing the table application side and building your query there, tho.